# Query in AchartEngine in android

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I am developing an android app, using AChartEngine for implementing the graphs in my application. Now I want to display the weekday name as the label for the x axis. Thank fully I am able to do it but the default labels (2,4,6,8,....) are still displaying. I have googled regarding it but won't be able to find the solution.  I have upload the image of concern below.[image: AChartEngine graph with two sets of labels displaying on X axis]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the X labels size to 1

```
 renderer.setXLabels(1);
```